# Android emulator won't load when splash screen is added

Tags: android, android-emulator, splash-screen

As is the emulator won't load. When I change the Splash theme in the themes.xml to link directly to the logo (instead of @drawable/splash_background which is a .xml file that indirectly calls the logo) the emulator does load, but the splash screen still doesn't display.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.settheme">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SetTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme = "@style/Splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.settheme.SecondActivity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**themes.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.SetTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
    <style name="Splash">
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add new empty activity witch give you two file >>one for your 'splashscreen.java' code and 'splashscreen_main.xml' after that add your splashscreen java code and add your logo to the 'splashscreen_main.xml' by adding it like image,and dont forget to access it in your 'AndroidManifest.xml'  then try agin , if i understand your question so do that first .